# ubuntu-sdk mkspec

Tags: ubuntu-touch, application-development, qt, ubuntu-sdk, qml

I followed instructions in [Ubuntu SDK](https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/start/ubuntu-sdk/installing-the-sdk/) to install the IDE. No problem. I can write an app and run it in the desktop, but not in my Ubuntu BQ 4.5. The kit is wrong and several errors appear: "Mkspec not found for qt version" in Figure 1[image: Figure 1], "qmake does not exist or is not executable" in Figure 2[image: Figure 2] and the compiler seem unknown in Figure 3[image: Figure 3].

Qt 5.2.1 and Qt-Creator 3.1.1 on Ubuntu 14.04. How can it be fixed?

Comment: Something has gone very wrong in the chroot associated with that kit.  I'm not sure what, unfortunately.  I'd be tempted to delete the existing chroot and kit and try again.

Comment: I tried to [upgrade and delete the chroot](https://lists.launchpad.net/ubuntu-phone/msg12055.html) but the first did not fix it and the second throw an error: KeyError: 'ubuntu-sdk.15.04'