# Can I create a click package for a html5 app without ubuntu SDK

Tags: ubuntu-touch, phone, html, click-packages

I recently read that ubuntu app store will not support click packages in a near future and our BQ Aquaris 4.5 will surely not support snaps.
Also I was unable to make Ubuntu SDK IDE run properly ([ubuntu-sdk mkspec](https://askubuntu.com/questions/687360/ubuntu-sdk-mkspec?noredirect=1#comment1002079_687360)). Purged it and reinstlled, but it got worse.
Could I write html5+js code in a text editor and create the cluck package for it somehow manually? Without using ubuntu-sdk-ide?
This way I could install it through UT Tweak Tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fit that template https://github.com/popey/ubuntu-html5-template to your project and run 'click build .' from the project's root directory. Then you should be able to install the newly created click package on your device via UT tweak tool.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try it. I also find [this one](https://github.com/Sturmflut/ubuntu-html5-webview-template), that includes a QML wrapper.